# Siege: descriptor table full sock.c:119: Too many open files

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, connection, socket, gcc

I am trying to make a stress test in my own server using siege with the following command:

```
$ siege -c 500 myweb.com/somefile.php
```

But I get this error:

```
[error] descriptor table full sock.c:119: Too many open files
```

And I get too this warning:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

But I am using Ubuntu 15.04 (Development branch) and I have installed the package libgcc1, so I don't know why it is complaning about that .so shared library.

How I can solve the too many open files and the libgcc warning?

Comment: Seems https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/siege/+bug/1317812. Anyway  try to increase the maximum amount of opened files with `ulimit -n 10000` or permanently (https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/).

Answer (score 12):

To solve this problem for myself, I had to adjust the OS "ulimit" setting:

`ulimit -a` -- Check current setting

`ulimit -n 10000` -- Edit setting value

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=595527

Comment: Then I got [error] socket: unable to connect sock.c:249: Operation already in progress

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the maximum number of files that can be open by the same user within the same session accordingly.

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Answer (score 0):

Error message is misleading<s>, but there's erorr in your command:</s>

```
$ siege -c 500 myweb.com/somefile.php
```

After `-c` you must specify number of consurrent simulated users.

Don't forget to check the rights for log file: by default it's `/var/log/siege.log`.

Or, specify your own by adding `--log=/home/user/siege.log`

Comment: I have the number 500 specified. Your answer is wrong

Comment: Yes, you are right. But check the log file anyway

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `gcc-multilib` helped me with it (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

`sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`